# null pointer in namedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
I am getting the namedParameterJBCtemplate as null value

    static String TABLE = "select * from cdh_spectrum_xstore_reg.%s";
    static String GET_TRANSACTION_BY_FILENAME = " where etl_source_name = :etlSourceName" + 
            " and pos_key in (select pos_key from cdh_spectrum_xstore_reg.pos_log where etl_source_name = :etlSourceName order by load_date desc limit 1)" + 
            " and batch_ts in (select batch_ts from cdh_spectrum_xstore_reg.pos_log where etl_source_name = :etlSourceName order by load_date desc limit 1)" +
            " limit 1";

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Transaction getIsolatedTransactionDetails(String fileName) {
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(String.format(TABLE, "pos_log") + GET_TRANSACTION_BY_FILENAME,
            new MapSqlParameterSource("etlSourceName", fileName),
            transactionMapper);
}
```

Here the filename is correctly coming when I debug What I noticed is namedParameterJdbcTemplate is giving null.

Comment: No it's. a null pointer issue.Its relate to template instatntiation.

Comment: Create a bean 
`@Bean
 public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
  return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
 }` and try

Comment: @sreyas Created still same issue.Can I share me screen?

Comment: ok please show the code